# IIS7 -- web services and web app coexist under Default Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am new to most aspects of IIS administration. My requirement is for the URL `www.mysite.com` to resolve to `www.mysite.com/myapp` when entered into a browser. However, `myapp` (not the real name) resides in Default Web Site (see green box) along with another directories that contain some web services (see red box in screenshot)  which use port 80. Also, `www.mysite.com` must run under SSL.

Here's a shot of the current setup. I have obscured the true names a bit.

[image]

I need to have `www.mysite.com` resolve to the app in the green box (call it `mysite.com/myapp`), but I don't know how to:

1) Set that up, in general.

2) Set that up without impacting the services in the red box.

I've done some reading on host headers and ARR, but it's still not clear to me how to solve the problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** added screenshot and details.

Comment: When you say the existing web services reside in "another virtual directory" - do you mean the URL on which these services are currently being called is something like www.mysite.com/services/products.asmx where /services is mapped to some other physical application directory? So that I understand the problem - you want the browser to do a redirect from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/myapp? Do you also want e.g. www.mysite.com/help to change to www.mysite.com/myapp/help?

Comment: @TomHall thanks for the reply. In short, yes, I want the user to enter `www.mysite.com` into the browser and end up going to `www.mysite.com/myapp`, which is a login page. I added some details to the question, which I hope are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using IIS [URL Rewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/734/url-rewrite-module/) module to look for requests that are **only** for `www.mysite.com`, and then redirect them to `www.mysite.com/myapp` and that seems to have worked.

I see that the cert error that I get with my self-signed cert is standard, until I add it to my browser's Trusted Root Cert Authority.

I'll upvote the first response to (and first comment on) my question. Thanks for pitching in.

Answer (score 1):

honestly, the quickest/easiest way i found to do this was to make default.htm file, put it in the wwwroot folder, and make the html file just do a redirect to the URL you want.

Comment: How should I set this up to work under SSL, though? I tried your suggestion and got a ***Wrong Site*** warning against my self-signed certificate.